# Data com problema no mysql e java

Tags: java, mysql

Eu estou tentando usar a data de um `jYearChoser` e um `jMonthChoser` para buscar a venda de um mês completo, já testei no prompt do MySQL e funcionou perfeitamente com o comando abaixo:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(vendas.total_pagar),2), FORMAT(SUM(desconto_venda),2), FORMAT(SUM(orcamentos.valor_orcamento),2), FORMAT(AVG(valor_venda),2), COUNT(vendas.id), COUNT(DISTINCT(vendas.id_cliente))
FROM genius.vendas
LEFT JOIN genius.orcamentos ON genius.orcamentos.id = id_orcamento
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `data_venda`) = (EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2016-08-01' - INTERVAL 0 MONTH)) AND vendas.Id_funcionario = 5;
```

Mas quando tento usar no Java da forma abaixo ele funciona, mas, a conta sai errada:

```
//abaixo preenche o painel cálculo de pagamento
    sql = "SELECT SUM(vendas.total_pagar), FORMAT(SUM(desconto_venda),2), FORMAT(SUM(orcamentos.valor_orcamento),2), FORMAT(AVG(valor_venda),2), COUNT(vendas.id), COUNT(DISTINCT(vendas.id_cliente))\n" +
                 "FROM genius.vendas\n" +
                 "LEFT JOIN genius.orcamentos ON genius.orcamentos.id = id_orcamento\n" +
                 "WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `data_venda`) = (EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM ?'-1' - INTERVAL 0 MONTH)) AND vendas.Id_funcionario = ?";
    try {
        int setar = tblFuncionarios.getSelectedRow();
        String id = (tblFuncionarios.getModel().getValueAt(setar, 0).toString());
        pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        // passando o Id para o "?
        pst.setString(1,Integer.toString(jYearChooser1.getYear()) + "-" + Integer.toString(jMonthChooser1.getMonth()));
        pst.setString(2, id);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            double vendas = (rs.getDouble(1));
            lblVendas.setText(Double.toString(vendas));
            lblDescontos.setText(rs.getString(2));
            lblOrcamentos.setText(rs.getString(3));
            lblVMC.setText(rs.getString(4));
            lblVendas_quant.setText(rs.getString(5));
            lblClientes.setText(rs.getString(6));

            if ("sim".equals(lblCG.getText())) { // a condição abaixo calcula a porcentagem para comissão gradativa
                double inicioCG = Double.parseDouble(lblCGInicio.getText());
                double intervaloCG = Double.parseDouble(lblCGIntervalo.getText());
                double maxPorcCG = Double.parseDouble(lblCGLimite.getText());
                int fator = (int) ((vendas - inicioCG) / intervaloCG + 1);
                lblCGPorc.setText(Integer.toString(fator));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: partes irrelevantes do código foram omitidas*

Comment: Gostaria de poder reproduzir este problema. Você consegue editar a sua pergunta de forma a deixar um código que reproduza o problema e que também seja compilável e executável? Além disso, qual é a sua string de conexão com o MySQL?

Comment: Por favor paste o valor de `jYearChooser1.getYear()`, o valor de `jMonthChooser1.getMonth()`, a saída da *query* no Java e a saída diretamente no SQL.

Comment: o valor de jYearChooser1.getYear() é "2016" e o de jMonthChooser1.getMonth() é "08"

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui arrumar o código, percebi que estava calculando o valor do mês anterior, resolvi o problema somando 1 no jMonthChooser1.getMonth(), o problema era que o primeiro mês da classe calendar começa em 0, já no MySQL o primeiro mês começa em 1, então estava dando diferença